# How do I check if cmake is greater or less then 3.13.4 with shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to check if my cmake version is greater to equal to 3.13.4 else if less than 3.13.4 build newer. Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
RESULT=$(cmake --version)
if [ "$RESULT" -ge 3.13.4 ]; then
      echo "you are using the latest version of cmake"
elif [ "$RESULT" -lt 3.13.4 ]; then
        cd /home/builduser
        mkdir cmake
        cd cmake
        apt install wget libssl-dev
        wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.22.2/cmake-3.22.2.tar.gz
        tar -xf cmake-3.22.2.tar.gz
        cd cmake-3.22.2
        ./configure
        make install
        cd /home/builduser
        rm -rf cmake
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU sort has a version-sort option `-V`:

```bash
cmp=3.13.4
ver=$(cmake --version | head -1 | cut -f3 -d" ")

mapfile -t sorted < <(printf "%s\n" "$ver" "$cmp" | sort -V)

if [[ ${sorted[0]} == "$cmp" ]]; then
    echo "cmake version $ver >= $cmp"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic way of doing this is to use `case`:

```sh
case $(cmake --version | awk '/cmake version/ {print $3}') in
[012].*|3.?|3.?.*|3.1[012]|3.1[012].*|3.13|3.13.[0123])
  echo Too old
  # Download and build
  ;;
*)
  echo OK;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but I think you have to break the version number into pieces and compare each piece; you can't use regular arithmetic, since, e.g. 3.9 < 3.14.

Probably there's something a bit prettier than this, but this is what I came up with:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get version and strip any extra junk
result="$(cmake --version | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')"
# major version number is what precedes first period
major="${result%%.*}"
# take what's left
remainder="${result#*.}"
# what precedes first period in the remainder is the minor version num.
minor="${remainder%.*}"
# revision is what's left after that
revision="${remainder#*.}"

# either the major must be higher, 
# or it must be the same and the minor must be higher
# or both must be the same and the release must be high enough
if [ "$major" -gt 3 ] ||
    ( [ "$major" -eq 3 ] &&
        ( [ "$minor" -gt 14 ] ||
            ( [ "$minor" -eq 14 ] && [ "$release" -ge 4 ] ))) ; then
    echo "you are using a version of cmake >= 3.14.4"
    # version is >= 3.14.4; do stuff
else
    echo "you are using an older version of cmake"
    # do older version stuff
fi
```

Another way would be to write a recursive function for comparing: a little longer but prettier and more flexible.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

version_equal_or_greater() {
    # read arguments
    a="$1"
    b="$2"
    # if they're identical return true (return code 0)
    if [ "$a" == "$b" ] ; then
        return 0
    fi
    # read numbers before first .
    amajor="${a%%.*}"
    bmajor="${b%%.*}"
    # if first is greater return true (return code 0)
    if [ "$amajor" -gt "$bmajor" ] ; then
        return 0
    fi
    # if first is less return false (return code 1)
    if [ "$amajor" -lt "$bmajor" ] ; then
        return 1
    fi
    # should be the same; compare remainders
    version_equal_or_greater "${a#*.}" "${b#*.}"
}

result="$(cmake --version | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')"

if version_equal_or_greater "$result" "3.14.4" ; then
    echo "you are using a version of cmake >= 3.14.4"
    # version is >= 3.14.4; do stuff
else
    echo "you are using an older version of cmake"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-lt` and `-gt` operators can only be used for numeric comparisons. "3.13.4" isn't a number; it's a version string. Assuming that we're using `bash`, we can write a `version_comp` function like this:

```
version_comp() {
    local min_version
    local have_version

    [[ "$1" == "$2" ]] && return 0

    mapfile -t -d. min_version <<<"$1"
    mapfile -t -d. have_version <<<"$2"

    for ((i=0; i<${#min_version[*]}; i++)); do
        if (( have_version[i] > min_version[i] )); then
            return 0
        elif (( have_version[i] < min_version[i] )); then
            return 1
        fi
    done

    return 0
}
```

We're using `mapfile` to split the version strings into arrays, which allows us to test each component numerically.

Now let's test it:

```
target=3.13.3

# Test versions greater than or equal to target
while read -r value; do
    if version_comp "$target" "$value"; then
        echo "PASSED: $value >= $target"
    fi
done << EOF
3.14.4
3.15.0
4
4.0.0
4.1.2
10
EOF

echo

# Test versions less than target
while read -r value; do
    if ! version_comp "$target" "$value"; then
        echo "PASSED: $value < $target"
    fi
done << EOF
2
1.2.3
3.14.2
0
EOF
```

Which produces:

```
PASSED: 3.14.4 >= 3.13.3
PASSED: 3.15.0 >= 3.13.3
PASSED: 4 >= 3.13.3
PASSED: 4.0.0 >= 3.13.3
PASSED: 4.1.2 >= 3.13.3
PASSED: 10 >= 3.13.3

PASSED: 2 < 3.13.3
PASSED: 1.2.3 < 3.13.3
PASSED: 0 < 3.13.3
```